# C# thread running python script

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, ironpython

I have several python scripts and would like to run them using .net thread pool, each thread running a python script (I have .net doing lot other stuff for me and towards the end needs to call this python script). How can I accomplish this?

I could start a process for each python script, but was hoping threading would be more efficient way to accomplish this.I am new to threading, any thoughts in right direction will help.

Update: just did a some more research that we can use Ironpython to run python script (by doing something like Python.CreateRuntime()) but i am not sure if that would it self create another process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, IronPython can be use for this purpose.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2009/10/25/hosting-ironpython-in-a-c-4-0-program.aspx for details on running a script from from .Net

Comment: can we run in each python script in a separate thread? or each time do createRuntime its going to create another process under the hood?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the internals. But I would suspect that if you `CreateRuntime` on a separate `thread` and then run the script it should work and you will not have any thread safety issues.

Comment: I suggest you create a new question on SO and tag it with IronPython.

Comment: sure, thank you! I will try with an example to see how it works.